# Calling a method from outside class with dependencies PHP

Tags: php, class, dependencies, composer-php

**Problem:**
I have an `index.php` file which has several composer dependencies.
Inside the `index.php` file i'm trying to call the static method from the outside class in a different php (let's say `auth.php`) file like this:

```
/*creating a class instance*/
$var = new AuthClass();

/*accessing an outside class method*/
$var = AuthClass::checkTime($tokenCode);
```

The issue is the `checkTime` method inside the class requires a composer dependency as well, which isn't inherited, although the file is located in the same folder as index.php and index.php is included.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Token' not found
```

I've tried everything - from adding require_once/include 'index.php' to copying the composer autoload to auth.php outside and inside the AuthClass code, but nothing works, i'm still getting the same error.

Additional code:

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/src/vendor/autoload.php';

$argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
$tokenCode = $_GET['tokenCode'];

include 'config/database.php';
include 'objects/program1.php';
include 'auth.php';

use ReallySimpleJWT\Token;
use Carbon\Carbon;

$secret = "somesecret";

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "GET") {

    if ($_GET['url'] == "bankquery") {

        if($tokenCode===NULL){
            echo "no correct token provided";
            print($results);
        } else {
        $results = Token::validate($tokenCode, $secret);
        if ($results = 1){

$var = new AuthClass();
$var = AuthClass::checkTime($tokenCode);

} else {
    echo "no correct token provided";
}
    }

} else {
    echo "some GET other query";
}

?>
```

**auth.php**

```
// loading composer
require __DIR__ . '/src/vendor/autoload.php';

//loading my index.php file
include 'index.php';

//using composer dependencies
use ReallySimpleJWT\Token;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthClass{

public static function checkTime($tokenCode){

// getting payload from token code by accessing the composer dependency method in a class Token
$received = Token::getPayload($tokenCode);

return $received;
}
}

?>
```

Need help, guys.

Comment: There is no enough information. Please provide some info about Token class

Comment: @DavitHuroyan provided the code

Comment: try \ before Token    " \Token" or try with namespace lets see what will return

Comment: And what is the content of `index.php`?

Comment: tried both the "\Token" and namespace "ReallySimpleJWT\Token" none worked, same error, unfortunately @DavitHuroyan

Comment: added the index.php content @rob006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `AuthClass` before it was defined - try move `include 'index.php';` line at the end of the file.

You should also include `vendor/autoload.php` only once - you don't need to repeat this in every file, just make sure that it is included at the top of the entry file which handles request.

But this is more like a result of design problem. You should define `AuthClass` in separate file and avoid any additional side effects in it - file should only define class. This is part of [PSR-1 rules](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/):

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.)
>   or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.)
>   but SHOULD NOT do both.

Since you're already using autoloader from Composer it should be relatively easy to register your own autoloading rules, so Composer's autoloader will take care about classes autoloading.

If at this point you're still getting `Class 'X' not found`, you probably did not installed some dependency or your autoloading rules are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to include your own code in the composer autoloading.
The [composer website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) tells you how to do it.

You don't need to require the composer files yourself and composer handles everything for you.

The [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) tells you how to namespace your code to use Namespacing.

Comment: I've added PSR-4 rule for composer.json to link my AuthSpace spacename with AuthClass, dumped autoload - it generated new psr-4 autoload files - BUT after executing index.php now the ReallySimpleJWT\Token isn't available. I'm assuming the require and PSR-4 in composer.json are exclusive.